# Getting redux state error while testing component in react

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs

This error occurred while testing redux in component

**could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a `<Provider>`**

How can I fix this.?

My index.js
[image]

The component that I want to test

[image]

Comment: It would help if you post your redux setup as part of the question

Comment: Check now in my index.js I wrap the app component as you can see in the image but when I want to use it in the component test it will throw this error

Comment: Can you confirm the component you are trying to test redux in is within the `App`?

Comment: Check my component

Comment: Yea I can see it. The only time this error occurs is if you are trying to use redux features out side the provider

Comment: so what can I do.?